# Utf8Json deserialize to type based on marker field

Tags: c#, utf8json

With `Json.NET - Newtonsoft` I have successfully used custom contract deserializers and json converter to select the deserializer based on a tag (in the case below `ev`).

In summary **I am looking to achieve the same with `Utf8Json`**, full details below:

```
// Stocks TRADE:
{
    "ev": "T",              // Event Type
    "sym": "MSFT",          // Symbol Ticker
    "x": "4",               // Exchange ID
    "i": 12345,             // Trade ID
    "z": 3,                 // Tape ( 1=A 2=B 3=C)
    "p": 114.125,           // Price
    "s": 100,               // Trade Size
    "c": [0, 12],           // Trade Conditions
    "t": 1536036818784      // Trade Timestamp ( Unix MS )
}

// Stocks QUOTE:
{
    "ev": "Q",              // Event Type
    "sym": "MSFT",          // Symbol Ticker
    "bx": "4",              // Bix Exchange ID
    "bp": 114.125,          // Bid Price
    "bs": 100,              // Bid Size
    "ax": "7",              // Ask Exchange ID
    "ap": 114.128,          // Ask Price
    "as": 160,              // Ask Size
    "c": 0,                 // Quote Condition
    "t": 1536036818784      // Quote Timestamp ( Unix MS )
}

// Stocks Aggregate:
{
    "ev": "AM",             // Event Type ( A = Second Agg, AM = Minute Agg )
    "sym": "MSFT",          // Symbol Ticker
    "v": 10204,             // Tick Volume
    "av": 200304,           // Accumulated Volume ( Today )
    "op": 114.04,           // Todays official opening price
    "vw": 114.4040,         // VWAP (Volume Weighted Average Price)
    "o": 114.11,            // Tick Open Price
    "c": 114.14,            // Tick Close Price
    "h": 114.19,            // Tick High Price
    "l": 114.09,            // Tick Low Price
    "a": 114.1314,          // Tick Average / VWAP Price
    "s": 1536036818784,     // Tick Start Timestamp ( Unix MS )
    "e": 1536036818784,     // Tick End Timestamp ( Unix MS )
}
```

And a text stream that can consist of any of the above types:

```
[{"ev":"A","sym":"DAL","v":1,"av":1, ...snipped...},{"ev":"T","sym":"MSFT","p":114.11,"x":"4","s":67,"t":1586418423607, ...snipped... }]
```

And deserialize to:

```
class Message
{
   List<Trade> Trades { get; set; }
   List<Quote> Quotes { get; set; }
   List<Aggregate> Aggs { get; set; }
}
```

I am currently doing this, which works, but doubt is as performant as direct deserialization into POCO:

```
var array = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<dynamic>(@"[{""ev"":""A"",""sym"":""AAL"",""v"":1500,""av"":119037385,""op"":12.64,""vw"":13.1,""o"":13.1,""c"":13.1,""h"":13.1,""l"":13.1,""a"":12.6655,""z"":500,""s"":1586472438000,""e"":1586472439000},{""ev"":""A"",""sym"":""AAL"",""v"":6000,""av"":119043385,""op"":12.64,""vw"":13.1,""o"":13.1,""c"":13.1,""h"":13.1,""l"":13.1,""a"":12.6655,""z"":1000,""s"":1586472439000,""e"":1586472440000},{""ev"":""A"",""sym"":""AAL"",""v"":3000,""av"":119046385,""op"":12.64,""vw"":13.11,""o"":13.11,""c"":13.11,""h"":13.11,""l"":13.11,""a"":12.6655,""z"":1000,""s"":1586472440000,""e"":1586472441000}]");

foreach(var item in array)
{
    if(item["ev"]=="A")
    {
        var aggregate = new OpenHighLowClose(
            DateTimeOffset.FromUnixTimeMilliseconds((long)item["s"]),
            (decimal)item["op"],
            (decimal)item["h"],
            (decimal)item["l"],
            (decimal)item["c"],
            (decimal)item["v"]);
    }
    else if(item["ev"=="AM"]) { }
    else if(item["ev" == "T"]) { }
    else if(item["ev" == "Q"]) { }
}
```

What is the *equivalent of json.net's JsonConverter* in **Utf8Json**, so I can switch the deserializer based on the EV field (and associated string value of either T, A, AM or Q)?

Just to add, i am going from JSON to and want to OpenHighLowClose POCO which I will then send out via message pack... is there any way to skip this intermediate step?

Comment: Can you guarantee that the `ev` field will always come first in a record?

Comment: yes it would be possible to assume that, ive not seen any data which doesnt have that out of millions of records.

Comment: It's certainly possible to skip intermediate steps, but it will require both manual handling of JSON tokens received from Utf8JsonReader _and_ manual creation of MessagePack byte stream. JSON maps pretty well onto MessagePack, so the code should be straightforward. I suggest asking a different question for that if you can't figure it out.

Comment: Please see this issue: https://github.com/neuecc/Utf8Json/issues/52. Create custom  IJsonFormatter<Message> and implement more or less what @AntonTykhyy described in his answer. Remember to  either decorate your `Message` class with   [JsonFormatter(typeof(MessageFormatter))] or register this formatter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can assume that the `ev` field always comes first in an object, it's possible to get away with minimum allocations and minimum extra parsing. In netcoreapp3.0 and later, `System.Text.Json` supports [custom type converters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-converters-how-to?view=netcore-3.1#support-polymorphic-deserialization), and one can write code like this:

```
[JsonConverter(typeof(MessageConverter))]
class Message
{
   List<Trade> Trades { get; set; }
   List<Quote> Quotes { get; set; }
   List<Aggregate> Aggs { get; set; }
}

public class MessageConverter : JsonConverter<Message>
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type typeToConvert) =>
        typeof(Message).IsAssignableFrom(typeToConvert);

    public override Message Read(ref Utf8JsonReader reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        if (reader.TokenType != JsonTokenType.StartArray)
            throw new JsonException();

        var message    = new Message();
        message.Trades = new List<Trade>();
        message.Quotes = new List<Quotes>();
        message.Aggs   = new List<Aggs>();

        while(Expect(ref reader, JsonTokenType.StartObject, JsonTokenType.EndArray))
        {
            Expect(ref reader, JsonTokenType.PropertyName);
            var propertyName = reader.GetString();
            if (propertyName != "ev")
                throw new JsonException();

            switch(ExpectString(ref reader))
            {
            default:
                throw new JsonException();
            case "T":
                var trade = new Trade();
                while(Expect(ref reader, JsonTokenType.PropertyName, JsonTokenType.EndObject))
                switch(reader.GetString())
                {
                default:    throw new JsonException();
                case "sym": trade.Symbol = ExpectString (ref reader); break;
                case "p":   trade.Price  = ExpectDecimal(ref reader); break;
                ...
                }
                message.Trades.Add(trade);
                break;
            ...
            }
        }

        return message;
    }

    public override void Write(Utf8JsonWriter writer, Message message, JsonSerializerOptions options) =>
        throw new NotSupportedException();

    private void Expect(ref Utf8JsonReader reader, JsonTokenType t)
    {
        reader.Read();
        if (reader.TokenType != t)
            throw new JsonException();
    }

    private string ExpectString(ref Utf8JsonReader reader)
    {
        Expect(ref reader, JsonTokenType.String);
        return reader.GetString();
    }

    private decimal ExpectDecimal(ref Utf8JsonReader reader)
    {
        Expect(ref reader, JsonTokenType.Number);
        return reader.GetDecimal();
    }

    private bool Expect(ref Utf8JsonReader reader, JsonTokenType a, JsonTokenType b)
    {
        reader.Read();
        if (reader.TokenType == a) return true ;
        if (reader.TokenType == b) return false ;
        throw new JsonException();
    }
}
```

If for some reason you can't use netcoreapp3.x, then you will have to forgo `JsonSerializer` for the outer `Message` and run the code in the `Read` method directly. If you are willing to spend a bit of cycles to avoid deserializing the inner objects manually, then apply `JsonPropertyName` attributes on your property names

```
struct Trade
{
    [JsonPropertyName("sym")]
    public string  Symbol { get; set; }
    [JsonPropertyName("p")]
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

and rewrite the outer loop of the `Read` method like this:

```
        while (Expect(ref reader, JsonTokenType.StartObject, JsonTokenType.EndArray))
        {
            // save reader state to peek the object type
            var copy = reader;

            Expect(ref copy, JsonTokenType.PropertyName);
            var propertyName = copy.GetString();
            if (propertyName != "ev")
                throw new JsonException();

            switch(ExpectString(ref copy))
            {
            default:
                throw new JsonException();
            case "T":
                message.Trades.Add(JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Trade>(ref reader));
                break;
            //...
            }
        }
```

Comment: Thanks Anton, for the arrays, how would i deal with this? I see JsonTokenType.StartArray, how to loop until the end (as the elements are dynamic)?

Comment: Which arrays do you mean specifically?

Comment: Under the `Trade` type we have an array for conditions `"c": [0, 12]`

Comment: You could write deserialization code manually, starting with `Expect(ref reader, JsonTokenType.StartArray)` and looping until you get an `EndArray` token, but if you're not after squeezing the very last percent of performance, I really suggest using the native serializer for `Trade`s and other interior objects, as in my last code snippet. Just add `[JsonPropertyName ("c")] public int[] Conditions { get ; set ; }` to `Trade` and you're set.

Answer (score 0):

What about a message that looks more like this:

```
class Message
{
   List<IStockItem> Items { get; set; }
}
```

IStockItem is an interface and the classes of type Trade, Quote and Aggregate inherit from IStockItem.

In your custom JsonConverter's ReadJson, you'll put your conditions for serialization based on the value of ev

```
public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.Null)
        {
            return string.Empty;
        }
        else if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.String)
        {
            return serializer.Deserialize(reader, objectType);
        }
        else
        {
            JObject obj = JObject.Load(reader);
            if (obj["ev"] != "A")
                return // Logic for A
            else if (obj["ev"] != "T")
                return // Logic for T
            else
                return serializer.Deserialize(reader, objectType);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks Ctznkane525 for taking the time to reply, I believe the above code would be for Json.net - appreciated, am ok with that thank you, looking for the equivalent in Utf8Json