# utf8json deserializing to multiple types based on marker field that does not come first

Tags: c#, utf8json

I have the following data:

Unlike a similair question here: [Utf8Json deserialize to type based on marker field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61116919/utf8json-deserialize-to-type-based-on-marker-field) the web service does not return the marker field (in the below case `primaryExch`) as the first item.

Essentially i would like to utf8json decode data into the following:

```
[
  {
    "ticker": "AAPL",
    "name": "Apple Inc.",
    "market": "STOCKS",
    "locale": "US",
    "currency": "USD",
    "active": true,
    "primaryExch": "NGS",
    "type": "cs",
    "codes": {
      "cik": "0000320193",
      "figiuid": "EQ0010169500001000",
      "scfigi": "BBG001S5N8V8",
      "cfigi": "BBG000B9XRY4",
      "figi": "BBG000B9Y5X2"
    },
    "updated": "2019-01-15T05:21:28.437Z",
    "url": "https://api.polygon.io/v2/reference/tickers/AAPL"
  },
  {
    "ticker": "$AEDAUD",
    "name": "United Arab Emirates dirham - Australian dollar",
    "market": "FX",
    "locale": "G",
    "currency": "AUD",
    "active": true,
    "primaryExch": "FX",
    "updated": "2019-01-25T00:00:00.000Z",
    "attrs": {
      "currencyName": "Australian dollar,",
      "currency": "AUD,",
      "baseName": "United Arab Emirates dirham,",
      "base": "AED"
    },
    "url": "https://api.polygon.io/v2/tickers/$AEDAUD"
  },
  { /* another stock */ },
  { /* another stock */ },
  { /* another FX*/ },
  { /* another stock */ },
  { /* another FX*/ }
  /* and so forth */
]
```

The URL property of hte base type, and currencyName and baseName of the FX type can be skipped as they are not required.

Into the following result:

```
class Response
{
   List<Stocks> Stocks{ get; set; }
   List<ForeignExchange> ForeignExchange { get; set; }
}
```

I would also be OK with a list of base types also `List<Ticker>` being returned:

class Ticker
{
string Ticker {get; set;}
string Name {get; set;}
MarketEnum Market {get; set;}
LocaleEnum Locale {get; set;}
CurrencyEnum Currency {get; set;}
bool Active {get; set;}
PrimaryExchEnum PrimaryExch {get; set;}
DateTimeOffset Updated {get; set;}
}

```
class Stock : Ticker
{
  int Type {get; set;}
  string CIK {get; set;}
  string FIGIUID {get; set;}
  string SCFIGI {get; set;}
  string CFIGI {get; set;}
  string FIGI {get; set;}
}

class ForeignExchange : Ticker
{
   BaseCurrencyEnum BaseCurrency {get; set;}
}
```

I can see how this is done in JSON.net as per [.NET Deserializing JSON to multiple types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12832306/net-deserializing-json-to-multiple-types) but after utf8json for the speed but ideally without stacks of low level deserializtion code.

As per my link originally referenced, [Utf8Json deserialize to type based on marker field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61116919/utf8json-deserialize-to-type-based-on-marker-field) i am unable to use the marker field since it does not come first and unsure of how to deal with this scenario efficiently.

```
public override List<Ticker> Read(ref Utf8JsonReader reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options)
{
    if (reader.TokenType != JsonTokenType.StartArray)
        throw new JsonException();

    var messages = new List<Ticker>();

    while(Expect(ref reader, JsonTokenType.StartObject, JsonTokenType.EndArray))
    {       
            // var message = new Ticker(); // cant do this as i dont know the type yet
            while(Expect(ref reader, JsonTokenType.PropertyName, JsonTokenType.EndObject))
            switch(reader.GetString())
            {
            default:    throw new JsonException();
            case "ticker": /* tickervar */ = ExpectString (ref reader); break;
            case "primaryExch": /* primaryExchvar */ = ExpectString (ref reader); break;
            case "codes": /* codesvar */ = ExpectStringArray (ref reader); break;
            case "attr": /* attrvar */ = ExpectStringArray (ref reader); break;
            ...
            }
            if(primaryExchvar == PrimaryExch.FX)
              message.Add(new ForeignExchange(tickervar, primaryExch, /* need to add the base from attr);
            else
              message.Add(new Stock(tickervar, primaryExch, /* need to add the items from codes);
            break;
        ...
        }
    }

    return messages;
}
```

I could store all deserialized property in a temporary dictionary, but this defeats the whole purpose of zero copy.

Also I am unsure how to flatten `codes` and `attr` arrays.

Any pointers much appreciated.

Comment: Can to share the code which does json deserialization? And explain what output you are getting with respect to expected output?

Comment: Hi @ChetanRanpariya I have not gotten to the point of writing code as the previous code i had written per https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61116919/utf8json-deserialize-to-type-based-on-marker-field specifically used the marker field that came first in the stream is not the same in this case